# Superfish menu - submenu - get many items to break

Tags: menu, joomla1.5, submenu, superfish

I have a long list with subitems which fall into the same category. As the submenu is growing, I want the submenu to break over in listing the sub menu items in 2 columns. Anybody out there knowing the trick how to do that?

see here illustrated my issue:

```
topmenu item
-submenu 1
-submenu 2
-submenu 3
-submenu 4
-submenu 5
-submenu 6
-submenu 7
-submenu 8
-submenu 9
-submenu 10
```

I need it to be like this:

```
topmenu item
-submenu 1   -submenu 6
-submenu 2   -submenu 7
-submenu 3   -submenu 8
-submenu 4   -submenu 9
-submenu 5   -submenu 10
```

Cheers from Denmark :-)

Jeannine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this using changing the css of superfish menu.

```
.sf-shadow ul {
    background: url("../images/shadow.png") no-repeat scroll right bottom transparent;
    padding: 0 8px 9px 0;
    width:300px;
}
```

and in

```
.sf-menu ul li {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Pramod :-) Thank you soooo much indeed! That was the key to solv the problem! You are my hero! Thank you!

Comment: uuuuupps, just another question.. is there any way to tell the system to apply the separation into 2 columns for submenus with more than 10 items only..?

Comment: We are doing this using css so there is no option of apply such condition..:)

Comment: Hello again. I was just thinking if there might be a possibility to add a class to the certain submenu items where we can apply the styles you suggested above? Can you also tell how to upvote and accept you?